# HttpURLConnection getting wrong response

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

Well, my php file includes simple code `<?php echo "hello there" ?>` 
Whenever I try read the file using `HttpURLConnection.getInputStream();` it returns

```
<html>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js"></script>
    <script>
        function toNumbers(d) {
            var e = [];
            d.replace(/(..)/g, function(d) {
                e.push(parseInt(d, 16))
            });
            return e
        }

        function toHex() {
            for (var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = "", f = 0; f < d.length; f++) e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16);
            return e.toLowerCase()
        }
        var a = toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),
            b = toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),
            c = toNumbers("b1fd294057e960f23314aeedeca32e65");
        document.cookie = "__test=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
        location.href = "http://classreminder.rf.gd/test.php?i=1";
    </script>
    <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
</body>

</html>
```

All I want is to just read the raw file.. only "hello there" .. not anything else.. how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is old and has been solved long ago. But here is something for people who is facing same issue:
Found out that my HttpURLConnection and my php file both was correct. But the server was running a browser check before executing any file. Thus I was unable to reach the php file endpoint. I simply changed the hosting and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you use, a `HttpURLConnection` or a web browser, the php file would always be executed at **server side** before being downloaded to client side, in this case, your phone. You can't do anything at client side to read the raw php file.

At server side you can rename the *.php file to *.html then you will always get a raw php file. But I don't think this is what you want... If you want to be able to read or edit php files from a phone you can use ftp or ssh.